# Opening compressed GDB in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase

Looking for help with a problem in QGIS. I'm using QGIS 2.2 and 2.4 for potential analysis of surfaces. Data are based in gdb datasets that were created in ArcGIS and made ​​available to me. Some gdb datasets I can easily insert as vector shapes. A set (2.5GB) but it makes problems. It opens only one layer of many layers from the data set. I was told by the supplier of the data that it is a compressed gdb, that should not be used otherwise than in the compressed form. ArcGIS can handle it.

Is it possible in QGIS for a setting to make or is there an extension that can handle that?

Answer (score 7):

GDAL can not handle compressed geodatabases and thus QGIS can't either because ESRI has not published the format. See this GDAL ticket http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5659.